# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isSubtree' for recursive functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm learning how to do binary tree functions in python, most of which are recursive, so I tried to run some leetcode solutions locally in my pycharm only to run into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LCPattern.py", line 55, in <module>
    a = Solution.isSubtree(self, t3,t4)
  File "LCPattern.py", line 39, in isSubtree
    return bool(s and t) and (is_the_same(s, t) or self.isSubtree(s.left, t) or self.isSubtree(s.right, t))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isSubtree'
```

code is

```
class Solution:
    def isSubtree(self, s: TreeNode, t: TreeNode) -> bool:

        def is_the_same(s, t):

            if not s and not t:
                # both s and t are empty
                return True

            elif s and t:
                # both s and t are non-empty
                # keep checking in DFS
                return s.val == t.val and is_the_same(s.left, t.left) and is_the_same(s.right, t.right)

            else:
                # one is empty, the other is non-empty
                return False

        # -----------------------------------------------------------
        return bool(s and t) and (is_the_same(s, t) or self.isSubtree(s.left, t) or self.isSubtree(s.right, t))

t3 = TreeNode(3)
t3.left = TreeNode(4)
t3.right = TreeNode(5)
t3.left.left = TreeNode(1)
t3.left.right = TreeNode(2)

t4 = TreeNode(4)
t4.left = TreeNode(1)
t4.right = TreeNode(2)

a = Solution.isSubtree(self, t3,t4)
print(a)
```

Apparently  `self.isSubtree(s.left, t)` is what's causing this error.
Can some one help me understand how to properly call recursive functions like these locally please?

Comment: change `a = Solution.isSubtree(self, t3,t4)` to `a = Solution().isSubtree(t3,t4)`

Comment: @UtpalKumar there's no problem using `or` and `and` in the return statement. It will simply return a boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the object wrong way -
Change this -

```
a = Solution.isSubtree(self, t3,t4)
```

to This

```
a = Solution()
a.isSubtree(t3,t4)
```